# The file mysqld.sock is removed and recreated constantly

Tags: mysql, linux, sockets, debian

This error appears to me:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through
socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I saw in others threads and no one help me, because it is created but in seconds is removed and recreated again...

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

That is not the error, it is a symptom.

Your mysql-server is dieing and restarting again probably from some error in configuration, or permissions in your system.

You should start by looking your syslog either /var/log/syslog or /var/log/messages to see what is happening with your mysqlserver when it starts.

If you don't see anything you can try starting mysqld from your root-shell and see what it sends to stdout/err.